# Peut-on dire "de par l'avenir" ?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, prépositions, indications-de-temps, locutions

Dans le contexte suivant, j'hésite entre plusieurs formulations :

> Je n'exclus cependant pas la possibilité de travailler avec vous **de par l'avenir**, si nous sommes amenés à nous rencontrer.

- de par l'avenir
- à l'avenir
- dans l'avenir

Le sens que j'essaie de faire passer en priorité est celui d'une rencontre improbable ayant lieu dans un futur relativement lointain.

Mes recherches de l'expression *de par l'avenir* ne donnent aucun résultat ou exemple d'utilisation concrète. Cette expression est-elle acceptable en français ?

Comment: On peut aussi omettre carrément *dans l'avenir/à l'avenir*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il y a une distinction [[OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2798)] à faire entre *à l'avenir* et *dans l'avenir*. Le premier signifie « à partir de maintenant », « dorénavant » et est souvent associé à un reproche fait à la situation présente. Le second signifie « un jour prochain », « un jour à venir », « ultérieurement ».

Dans cette phrase « dans l'avenir » est donc ce qui convient le mieux. « À l'avenir », avec d'autres changements dans la phrase, pourrait être utilisé pour signifier qu'il n'était pas envisageable de travailler avec eux, mais que maintenant ça l'est.

La locution *de par* [[TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/par/2), [Wikt.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_par)] existe avec plusieurs significations, dont une qui est « du fait de »/« à cause de », mais celle-ci ne convient pas dans cette phrase. L'autre signification « disséminé »/« quelque part » est généralement spatiale, et n'est que très rarement utilisée en référence au temps (« de par les siècles »). C'est dans tous les cas bien trop surprenant pour être utilisé dans une situation normale.

Comment: I’m wondering if without the “de,” do you think that it would be possible to fit just “**par l’avenir**” (which I find to be a rather cool phrase/image) into Jérôme’s sentence to emphasize the desired sense of ‘improbability’ (especially with ‘jamais’ added, but even without it) without having to rely on the distinction between “dans l’avenir” and à l'avenir?  For example: « Je n'exclus cependant pas la possibilité de travailler avec vous, si [jamais] nous sommes amenés **par l'avenir** à nous rencontrer. »  (cc : @Jérôme )

Comment: *Par l'avenir* does not sound right. *Si l'avenir nous amène à nous rencontrer* could be fine. Is that what you want to express ? For some reason I don't think the passive voice can be used here.

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly the notion I was after and I agree that the active voice, as is usually the case, is much better than how I tried to use the passive to express it. I guess I was trying to see if ‘l’avenir’ could be used in the passive voice with [physical action verbs +]  ‘par’ to sound similar to using “le destin” like that: “[Ré]unis/amenés/portés par le destin.”  I now see, however, that “par l’avenir” works best (if not only) to passively express mental states like: “Terrifié par …/ préoccupé par … l’avenir.”  Thanks for answering!

Comment: similitude malheureuse possible avec "par le passé". Mais je n'ai jamais vu "de par le passé". L'expression "de par" est plutôt sinonyme de "à cause de" / "en raison de" ...  = du fait de dans l'explication / sauf dans une construction comme de par son passé (douteux ...) - on pourrait en déduire un "de par son avenir supposé" ...

Answer (score 2):

Seul [*à l'avenir* et *dans l'avenir*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0%20l%27%20avenir%2Cdans%20l%27%20avenir&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20l%20%27%20avenir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20l%20%27%20avenir%3B%2Cc0) sont valables ; ils ont le même sens dans le langage actuel.

*Dans l'avenir* peut être 'nuancé'  :

> Dans  un proche avenir.

La phrase  surlignée dans la question est rendue incorrecte par l'utilisation de *de par l'avenir*.